# Sprint Cloud Stream Kafka Streams Binder processor application stuck

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I have the following Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Streams Binder 3.x application:

[image]

When I run X messages through this application by publishing them to the `topic1` from an integration test using `@SpringBootTest` and `@EmbeddedKafka` the counts of messages at points 1 and 2 are equal, as I expect.

When I do the same using live application connected to the Kafka broker, the counts at point 1 and point 2 remain significantly different: `Count1 >> Count2`.

Kafka Tool shows a big Lag of the `Processor2` consumer on the `topic2` and that lag remains constant (doesn't change after I stop publishing messages)

The `Processor2` consists of

- flatTransform stateful transformer
- aggregator
- other downstream steps

What could be the reason of the distinct behaviour during test and live mode and Lag not going down in live mode?

I have thoroughly compared all application property values active in test and in live application, they are exactly equivalent.

There is only 1 partition in all topics in both cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the reason was default 7 days retention setting of the topics that were automatically created by the Spring Cloud Stream application.

The messages in my input stream span 8 years, I am using custom TimestampExtractor.

After I have manually configured topics to a large retention time, the issue was solved:

```
/usr/bin/kafka-configs --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --alter --entity-type topics --entity-name topic2 --add-config retention.hours=87600
```

Or set the `log.retention.hours` for the entire Kafka broker.